# Why ad accounts are not showing in advertising accounts

Tags: facebook-marketing-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.8

I have used Facebook graph API v2.8 and created 35 ad accounts in business manager but none of them showing in advertising list under FB APP > Settings > Advanced > Advertising Accounts. After searching a lot I could not get anything. Any suggestions what could be the reasons?

[image]

Comment: Which list are we talking about?

Comment: All ad accounts those are created in business manager should be visible here but they are not showing

Answer (score 0):

This list contains the Ad Accounts able to measure app installs from your app, "from where your app is visible", not the other way around. The Ad Accounts your app will be able to read/write depends on the token permissions.
More: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/sdk